# how to find Thevenin Equivalent Voltage and Thevenin Equivalent Resistance?

Tags: voltage, resistance, thevenin, nodal-analysis, mesh-analysis

[image: thevenin equivalent circuit]

pls help me solve this question it’s confusing me

Comment: which part is confusing you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding the Thevenin equivalent resistance, you need to short circuit the independent voltage sources and open circuit the independent current sources. For finding the Thevenin voltage, find the open-circuit voltage Voc. A nodal analysis will get you there. You'd get Rth as 2 Ohm and VTh as 3 V
In which part are you stuck in?

Comment: thankyou so much

Comment: how do you get 2 ohm for RTH i got 6 ohm.For VTH i got 3V

Comment: 3 Ohm and 6 Ohm resistors are in parallel. The resulting combination is in series with 2 Ohm resistor. This resultant is again parallel with the 4 Ohm resistor.

Answer (score 1):

I think that simple circuits like this should be simply solved by inspection.
Let's note the node **A** in figure.
[image]

Now, looking the right side of the circuit, from **A** down to (-) terminal, you can note a parallel of 6//(4+2) = 3 ohms.
At this point, considering the left side too, we will have a very simple circuit with 9 V and two 3 ohms series resistance; therefore, the voltage on point **A** is 9/2 V.
Knowing the voltage at node **A**, it's easy to calculate the voltage level Vo, considering the voltage divider : Vo = (9/2)* 4/(2+4) = 3 V

Answer (score 0):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2femHIM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_6
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, we can set up a Mathematica-code to solve for all the voltages and currents:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I3 == I4 + I5, I6 == I4 + I5, I1 == I2 + I6, 
   I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == V1/R2, I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, I4 == V2/R4, 
   I5 == V2/R5}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, V1, V2}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> (((R2 + R3) R4 + (R2 + R3 + R4) R5) Vi)/(
   R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + 
    R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5), 
  I2 -> ((R4 R5 + R3 (R4 + R5)) Vi)/(
   R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + 
    R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5), 
  I3 -> (R2 (R4 + R5) Vi)/(
   R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + 
    R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5), 
  I4 -> (R2 R5 Vi)/(
   R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + 
    R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5), 
  I5 -> (R2 R4 Vi)/(
   R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + 
    R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5), 
  I6 -> (R2 (R4 + R5) Vi)/(
   R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + 
    R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5), 
  V1 -> (R2 (R4 R5 + R3 (R4 + R5)) Vi)/(
   R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + 
    R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5), 
  V2 -> (R2 R4 R5 Vi)/(
   R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + 
    R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5)}}
```

Now, we can find:

- \$\text{V}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{V}_2\$ and letting \$\text{R}_5\to\infty\$:
  $$\text{V}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{R}_4\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag3$$
- \$\text{I}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{I}_5\$ and letting \$\text{R}_5\to0\$:
  $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{R}_2\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_2\text{R}_3+\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\tag4$$
- \$\text{R}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding:
  $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{th}}{\text{I}_\text{th}}=\frac{\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_2\text{R}_3+\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)}{\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag5$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-codes:

```
In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(R2 R4 R5 Vi)/(
  R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + 
   R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5), R5 -> Infinity]]

Out[2]=(R2 R4 Vi)/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4))

In[3]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(R2 R4 Vi)/(
  R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + 
   R1 (R2 + R3 + R4) R5), R5 -> 0]]

Out[3]=(R2 Vi)/(R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3))

In[4]:=FullSimplify[%2/%3]

Out[4]=((R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) R4)/(R2 (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4))
```

So, using your values we get:

- $$\text{V}_\text{th}=3\space\text{V}\tag6$$
- $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{3}{2}=1.5\space\text{A}\tag7$$
- $$\text{R}_\text{th}=2\space\Omega\tag8$$

Comment: Although this is a *possible* solution, it is worth pointing out that it is *absolute overkill* and no sane engineer would use it in practice (it could be a learning experience, though). The whole point of the kind of exercises like the one in the OP is to make the future engineer develop the skills to do back-of-the-envelope calculations. In particular, with the nice values in the OP, the problem can be solved almost entirely "in one's head" by repeatedly applying the formulas for parallel/series resistors and for voltage dividers, which any engineer ***MUST*** get to know by heart.